# Put data between foreach() in PHP

Tags: php

How can I put data between specific results in the foreach() function?, I have an array like this:

```
array('01:data1:data2:data3', '01:data4:data5:data6', '02:data1:data2:data3')
```

When I print the array with `foreach()` I want to put html code between each number, like:

```
<ul>
<li>01:data1:data2:data3</li>
<li>01:data4:data5:data6</li>
</li>Image</li>
<li>02:data1:data2:data3</li>
<li>Image</li>
</ul>
```

Is it possible?

Comment: yes, you can put. edit your question and show me how you want to show and where you want to add it.

Comment: 1) invalid html | 2) how you define when `Image` appear?

Comment: i'd worry more about your array format than how to parse that. try multi-dimensional arrays - easier to parse with nested loops.

Comment: Objects are event more easier to work with :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$currentNumber = null;

foreach ($array as $data) {
    $number = current(explode(':', $data));
    if ($number != $currentNumber) {
        echo '<li>Image</li>';
    }
    $currentNumber = $number;

    ...
}
```

Comment: Yes thats it! you just left print $data and else{}.